# Co-quasitriangular Hopf algebra - notation

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

In one article I found the following statement :

> If $A$ is a Hopf algebra over $k$ with co-quasitriangular structure $r$, then one can define map $r_{21}*r:A\otimes A\rightarrow k \ \ $  (...).

How should we understand the above statement? If $\sigma:A\otimes A\rightarrow B$ then we define $\sigma_{12}=\sigma\otimes \mathrm{id}$ on $A\otimes A\otimes A$ etc., but in this case in the domain there are only two copies of $A$.

($*$ means convolution product)

Comment: Maybe it means $r \circ T$, where $T$ is the twist? (This is just a guess motivated by the fact that $\sigma_{ij}$ often means "$\sigma$ acting on the tensorands $i$ and $j$ in this order".)

Comment: Such questions are always better with a link/reference to the article, btw.

Comment: It is from http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112299v2 p.29. I was inspired the case of quasitriangular structure where there are at least three factors. Probably you have right and it only means composition with twist. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it usually means $r_{21} = TrT$ where $Tx\otimes y=y\otimes x$ is the canonical flip

Comment: Namely, the numbers in the subscript denote on which tensor factors the operator acts. If $r = s\otimes t$, then $r_{21} = t \otimes s$ on $A\otimes A$, $r_{13}=s \otimes id \otimes t$ on $A \otimes A\otimes A$ etc